# How to put 605 custom fonts in iPad application

Tags: iphone, ipad

I put some custom fonts in the resources and add some entries to the plist file so I can use them... and everything is working fine... But my app needs to use 605 custom fonts and when I add more than 240 or 245 fonts the application won't respond to the fonts.. i.e. when I write some text using any of those fonts, nothing appears, when I reduce them to 240 fonts, text appears again

Any idea?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine when 605 fonts might be required in an app!... Are you making a Photoshop type clone for the iPad?

Answer (score 0):

Oh by the way just to make it clearer, it doesn't matter how many fonts I add to the resources as long as it's less than 250 entry in the plist for them... so even if I add 1000 fonts files to the resources and having only 240 entry for 240 of them in the plist, those 240 will work

Answer (score 0):

btw did u try using through uiwebview or coretext? I never try with that many fonts but may be u can post fonts or something so that we can also try that (bcoz it would be very difficult to download fonts and then put into plist)

Comment: are u using uiwebviews or simple views? also it would be nice if u share the code where u put 700fonts bcoz then we can see what u are doing.